# Add child with multiple columns to qtreeview in pyside

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview

How do I add children nodes as seen in the image below. I know how to add a single row and a child. However I get stuck when trying to add a child node that has a checkbox in the second column.

[image]

```
import sys
import os
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Soccer(object):
    def __init__(self,  name='', team=''):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.op_forward = True
        self.op_goalie = False

class Football(object):
    def __init__(self, name='', team=''):
        self.name = name
        self.team = team
        self.op_quarterback = False
        self.op_center = False
        self.op_coach = False

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        # variables
        self.assets = [
            Soccer(name='Doug', team='Nailers'),
            Soccer(name='Leslie', team='Sonics'),
            Football(name='Kevin', team='Patriots'),
            Football(name='Matt', team='Cowboys'),
        ]

        # create widgets
        lb_simulators = QtGui.QLabel('Simulators')
        lb_simulators.setProperty('class', 'section')

        self.items_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.ui_items = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.ui_items.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.ui_items.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.ui_items.setAllColumnsShowFocus(True)
        self.ui_items.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_items.header().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)
        self.ui_items.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.ui_items.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.ui_items.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.ui_items.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.ui_items.setModel(self.items_model)
        self.ui_items.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.ui_items.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 8, QtGui.QFont.Normal))

        # layout
        grid = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        grid.setContentsMargins(10,10,10,10)
        grid.addWidget(lb_simulators)
        grid.addWidget(self.ui_items)

        # main layout
        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        self.create_model()

    def create_model(self):
        model = self.ui_items.model()
        model.clear()
        headers = ['Name', ''] # 'Sim', 'Continue', 'Wavelet/Resim', 'Post']
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
        self.ui_items.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

        for x in self.assets:
            model.insertRow(0)

            # Append object
            model.setData(model.index(0, 0), x, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            model.setData(model.index(0, 0), x.name)
            model.setData(model.index(0, 1), x.team)

            # if isinstance(x, Football):
            #     item = model.itemFromIndex(model.index(0,0))


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) method sets the value for the specified [data role](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). The role to make items checkable is `Qt.CheckStateRole`, and the values are given by the [check-state enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#CheckState-enum).

So the second column in your example can be made checkable like this:

```
model.setData(model.index(0, 1), x.team)
model.setData(model.index(0, 1), QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
```

However, if you're using a `QStandardItemModel`, it provides a more readable syntax, so your loop to populate the treeview could be re-written like this:

```
for x in self.assets:
    column1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(x.name)
    column1.setData(x, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    column2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(x.team)
    column2.setCheckable(True)
    model.appendRow([column1, column2])
```